# Making mixed numeric and alpha entry easier for mobile browers

Tags: css, blackberry, wap

I'm refurbishing a simple web-app that our field techs use. One of my goals is to make it Blackberry-friendly, as all of the techs are now using those. This app accepts basic information about a job and stores it. Among that info are times, telephone numbers, and a street address.

I have the time fields and telephone fields figured out with the following CSS:

```
     input.time  { -wap-input-format: "NN\\:NN"; }
     input.phone { -wap-input-format: "\\(nnn\\)\\ nnn\\-nnnn" }
```

What I'm trying to do is determine how I can have the phone default to numeric input on an address field, then go alpha once a space has been inserted. I'm assuming that this can't be done with the `-wap-input-format` property above.

Is there another way`--`even if it's only for the Blackberry Browser`--`to do this without resorting to JavaScript? (Not that there's anything wrong with that :-) )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a "Street Number" field followed by a separate "Street Name" field?  There is no way to have a variable number of digits at the start of this sort WAP input field without using JavaScript.

Comment: This seems to be the best way. I wanted to avoid cluttering the interface too much, but usability trumps prettiness any day. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on how you style your text inputs, there's no reason for the two fields to have any more clutter than the vertical separator between them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that javascript alone is the only way to do a decent job of subtle user input validation. Markup creates more challenges than it solves. With js you can let whatever keystrokes mean whatever you want, customized to any context.